# Best practice to store keys associated with a class

Tags: java, android

Is it better practice to store a set of key-value pairs used in a class in a separate interface or is it better practice to store it in strings.xml ?

e.g. :

```
public interface PreferenceKeys {
    static final String PREF1 = "pref1";
    static final String PREF2 = "pref2";
}
```

And then access it in my code as PreferenceKeys.PREF1

vs.

Storing as name-value pairs in string.xml:

```
<string name="PREF1">pref1</string>
<string name="PREF2">pref2</string>
```

And then accessing it in my class as:

```
String pref1 = getResources().getString(R.string.PREF1);
```

Comment: store it in java if you can. store it in conf file if you have to.

Comment: Why would one save preference key in interface??? The thing is that one can define preferences in xml file (PreferenceScreen, PreferenceCategory, etc..). In that case one should define android:key value and from there we can not access java class. Same for android:defaultValue

Answer (score 3):

I want to share what I did for preferences storage, I use android's build in feature called [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). For easy access, I create a wrapper around `SharedPreferences` called `UserModel` that have codes like this:

```
package tv.gsgw.android.garusuta.model;

import id.flwi.util.ActivityUtil;
import tv.gsgw.android.garusuta.constant.DataConstant;
import android.content.Context;

public class UserModel implements DataConstant {
    Context _context;

    private String authKey = "";
    private String email = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String birthdate = "";
    private String prefacture = "";
    private String bloodType = "";
    private String idealBodyType = "";
    private String duration = "";
    private String stability = "";
    private String skin = "";
    private String relationship = "";
    private String height = "";
    private String weight = "";
    private boolean registerDataChange = false;

    public UserModel(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        loadFromPreferences();
    }

    public void loadFromPreferences(){
        setAuthKey(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_AUTHKEY, ""));
        setEmail(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_EMAIL, ""));
        setPassword(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PASSWORD, ""));
        setBirthdate(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BIRTHDATE, ""));
        setPrefacture(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PREFACTURE, ""));
        setBloodType(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BLOODTYPE, ""));
        setIdealBodyType(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BODYTYPE, ""));
        setPeriod(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_DURATIONPERIOD, ""));
        setStability(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_STABILITY, ""));
        setSkin(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_SKINTYPE, ""));
        setRelationship(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_RELATIONSHIP, ""));
        setHeight(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_HEIGHT, ""));
        setWeight(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceString(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_WEIGHT, ""));
        setRegisterDataChange(ActivityUtil.getSharedPreferenceBoolean(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_REGISTER_DATACHANGE, false));
    }

    public void saveIntoPreferences(){
        saveIntoPreferences(true);
    }
    public void saveIntoPreferences(boolean datachanged){
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_AUTHKEY, getAuthKey());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_EMAIL, getEmail());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PASSWORD, getPassword());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BIRTHDATE, getBirthdate());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PREFACTURE, getPrefacture());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BLOODTYPE, getBloodType());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BODYTYPE, getIdealBodyType());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_DURATIONPERIOD, getPeriod());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_STABILITY, getStability());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_SKINTYPE, getSkin());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_RELATIONSHIP, getRelationship());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_HEIGHT, getHeight());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_WEIGHT, getWeight());
        ActivityUtil.setSharedPreference(_context, USER_DATA_FIELD_REGISTER_DATACHANGE, datachanged);
    }

    public String getAuthKey() {
        return authKey;
    }

    public void setAuthKey(String authKey) {
        this.authKey = authKey;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getPrefacture() {
        return prefacture;
    }

    public void setPrefacture(String prefacture) {
        this.prefacture = prefacture;
    }

    public String getBloodType() {
        return bloodType;
    }

    public void setBloodType(String bloodType) {
        this.bloodType = bloodType;
    }

    public String getIdealBodyType() {
        return idealBodyType;
    }

    public void setIdealBodyType(String idealBodyType) {
        this.idealBodyType = idealBodyType;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setPeriod(String period) {
        this.duration = period;
    }

    public String getSkin() {
        return skin;
    }

    public void setSkin(String skin) {
        this.skin = skin;
    }

    public String getRelationship() {
        return relationship;
    }

    public void setRelationship(String relationship) {
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public boolean isRegisterDataChange() {
        return registerDataChange;
    }

    public void setRegisterDataChange(boolean registerDataChange) {
        this.registerDataChange = registerDataChange;
    }

    public String getStability() {
        return stability;
    }

    public void setStability(String stability) {
        this.stability = stability;
    }

    public void setRegistrationChanged(boolean dataChange) {
        this.registerDataChange = dataChange;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String str = "";

        str += "authKey: " + authKey + "\n";
        str += "email: " + email + "\n";
        str += "password: " + password + "\n";
        str += "birthdate: " + birthdate + "\n";
        str += "prefacture: " + prefacture + "\n";
        str += "bloodType: " + bloodType + "\n";
        str += "idealBodyType: " + idealBodyType + "\n";
        str += "duration: " + duration + "\n";
        str += "stability: " + stability + "\n";
        str += "skin: " + skin + "\n";
        str += "relationship: " + relationship + "\n";
        str += "height: " + height + "\n";
        str += "weight: " + weight + "\n";
        str += "registerDataChange: " + (registerDataChange ? "true" : "false") + "\n";

        return str;
    }

}
```

`DataConstant` in code above is just a class that contain constant variable like this:

```
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_AUTHKEY = "new_AuthKey";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_EMAIL = "new_Email";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PASSWORD = "new_Password";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BIRTHDATE = "new_Birthday";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PREFACTURE = "new_Prefacture";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BLOODTYPE = "new_BloodType";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_BODYTYPE = "new_IdealBodyType";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_DURATIONPERIOD = "new_Duration";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_STABILITY = "new_Stability";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_SKINTYPE = "new_Skin";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_RELATIONSHIP = "new_Relationship";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_HEIGHT = "new_Height";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_WEIGHT = "new_Weight";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PHY_1 = "new_phy1";
public static final String USER_DATA_FIELD_NAME_PHY_2 = "new_phy2";
```

This use an utility class that also create to help working with `SharedPreferences` easier:

```
package id.flwi.util;

/**
 * @author Arief Bayu Purwanto
 */
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ActivityUtil {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "____MyPrefsFile";

    public static void debugExtra(Bundle extras){
        if( extras != null) {
            Log.i("Log", "printing all extras information");
            java.util.Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
            java.util.Iterator<String> keyIterator = keys.iterator();
            int index = 0;
            while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                Log.i("log", "  extras #" + (++index) + ": " + keyIterator.next());
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("Log", "empty extras");
        }
    }

    public static boolean getSharedPreferenceBoolean(Context c, String preference){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return settings.getBoolean(preference, false);
    }
    public static boolean getSharedPreferenceBoolean(Context c, String preference, boolean defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return settings.getBoolean(preference, defaultValue);
    }
    public static String getSharedPreferenceString(Context c, String preference){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return settings.getString(preference, "");
    }
    public static String getSharedPreferenceString(Context c, String preference, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return settings.getString(preference, defaultValue);
    }
    public static int getSharedPreferenceInt(Context c, String preference, int defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return settings.getInt(preference, defaultValue);
    }

    public static long getSharedPreferenceLong(Context c, String preference, long defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return settings.getLong(preference, defaultValue);
    }

    public static void setSharedPreference(Context c, String preference, boolean prefValue){

        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(preference, prefValue);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void setSharedPreference(Context c, String preference, Long prefValue){

        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong(preference, prefValue);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void setSharedPreference(Context c, String preference, int prefValue){

        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt(preference, prefValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void setSharedPreference(Context c, String preference, String prefValue){
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(ActivityUtil.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(preference, prefValue);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Using it is pretty simple:

1. To load the data, you just have to call:

   ```
   UserModel sharedData = new UserModel(getApplicationContext());
   ```
2. To change or retrieve data just call it's associated field getter/setter:

   ```
   sharedData.getPassword();
   sharedData.setPassword("new password");
   ```
3. Finally, if you change field(s), just don't forget to call `saveIntoPreferences`:

   ```
   sharedData.saveIntoPreferences();
   ```

Hope this help to solve your problem.

Comment: This is right answer. Other answers are simple nonsense but I guess at the time other authors were not interested in Android. The thing is that Preferences can be defined in xml layouts as well and at that location key and default value should be supplied as well. There is a problem if those are defined in java class cause from xml we will not have access to those constants

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, try to minimize the use of "context" in your project to avoid memory leaks or loading innecesary resources.

The shared preferences are a good option but needs to use the context of application or activit. Frequently used when you want persist some dynamic values, is this the case?.

Java interfaces only use final members (static) and are very compact and easy to use (remember) in the code. Try to use always you have static inmutable members (like ip, passwords, etc.).

Also, use enums to manage states or another things in your application, by example

```
public  interface Preferences {
    public String HOST = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    public String PREF1 = "pref1";
    public String PREF2 = "pref2"; 
    public enum Connection { CONNECTED, DISCONNECTED, UNKNOWN }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to use java class or in sharedPreference, the diffenerce between them is your purpose.
In my opinion, if you want save constants just use java class which extends Enum. 
Otherwise, user data, session data saved in sharedPreference, you can refer ariefbayu's answer, but in my advise use reflect to get your field's value.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `strings.xml` for resources that need to be used in layout files.
For variables that need to be accessed in class I prefer the `interface` way.